# Resource leak or not (Mac OS X)?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, memory-leaks

I'm trying to enumerate local users on Mac os.
It works correctly, but i think that there is
some resource leak. I can't understand that.
Profiling says that there are no memory leaks,
but memory usage are constantly grows (Memory Report
chart at XCode). In my case since 2.7M to 4.9M (5 * 1000 iterations).
Can anybody say what is wrong with my code.
Are there any leaks or the behaviour is normal?

This is a simple c++ command line tool project
with Objective-c code with default build settings (XCode 5):

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp

#include "test.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  //for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Iteration # " << i << std::endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
    {
      Execute();
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }

  return 0;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////
// test.mm

#import <Collaboration/Collaboration.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCDynamicStore.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific.h>

#include <iostream>

void Execute()
{
  CSIdentityAuthorityRef identityAuthority = CSGetLocalIdentityAuthority();
  if (!identityAuthority)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to get identity authority." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  CSIdentityQueryRef usersQuery(CSIdentityQueryCreate(nil,  kCSIdentityClassUser, identityAuthority));
  if (!usersQuery)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to create query." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Without CSIdentityQueryExecute(usersQuery, 0, nil) - everething is ok.
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (!CSIdentityQueryExecute(usersQuery, 0, nil))
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to execute query." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  CFRelease(usersQuery);
}


#ifndef __MY_TEST_H__
#define __MY_TEST_H__

void Execute();

#endif
```

Comment: Could it be that you aren't releasing `CSIdentityAuthorityRef`? Or maybe you could try to execute the `CFRelease` before every return. (I don't know, it's just an idea)

Comment: @DaniBarcaCasafont No and Yes

Comment: Ok i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Apples code has occasional leaks as well. So the leaking memory might not be something that you can fix. With 1kB per iteration it's a small leak, that shouldn't really matter in a real world example. You don't have to create a list of accounts constanlty. You should `CFRelease(usersQuery);` before you return because "Failed to execute query." though. But unless your code hit the error 5000 times that won't be the problem.

Comment: delete. will answer later.

Comment: The code should work 24x7. I can't ignore any leak.
Theoretically, you are right about CFRelase berore each return.
But before each of this return i have a trace. 
There are no any fail trace during execution.
So this not a solution of my trouble.

Comment: Moreover as was mentioned in code, if i comment the lines:

    if (!CSIdentityQueryExecute(usersQuery, 0, nil))
    {
      std::cout << "Failed to execute query." << std::endl;
      return;
    }

Everything is good. So i think, that the trouble appears inside this CSIdentityQueryExecute.
And my second theory:
The 'CSIdentityQueryExecute'  fills the usersQuery with some objects, that should be
released by some way (i don't know how) before CFRelease(usersQuer);

Comment: There is no reason to believe that `CSIdentityQueryExecute` inserts data that must be separately freed. That would be completely unlike every other part of Core Foundation. Try running my simplified form (linked in my answer), and see if it leaks for you (it does not for me, and it is somewhat unlikely this framework is leaking this way). If not, then the problem is in your C++ smart pointers. Check Instruments/Allocations to see what the accumulated memory actually is.

Comment: I tried your "slightly simplified". There is no fail log message, no leak at profiler, but usage of memory permanently grows. I will try one ugly method with calling of system "dscl" and parse it's output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the `CFRelease` before every `return` since some iterations are not releasing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this program, and I'm not seeing any memory growth. I [slightly simplified it](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/8935020) to be a single-file C++ program (currently it's a mix of C++ and ObjC++).

You do have a memory mistake, but I would only expect it to cause a leak if you were getting errors. This block leaks the query:

```
if (!CSIdentityQueryExecute(usersQuery, 0, nil))
{
  std::cout << "Failed to execute query." << std::endl;
  return;
}
```

You should either not return here (you don't technically need to), or you should include a `CFRelease(usersQuery)` before the return. But again, if this were the problem, you'd see lots of "Failed to execute query" log messages.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is still there. In real code i use std::unique_ptr (
typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<CSIdentityQueryRef>::type, ObjcReleaser> CSIdentityQueryUniquePtr;
CSIdentityQueryUniquePtr usersQuery(CSIdentityQueryCreate(nil,  kCSIdentityClassUser, identityAuthority));)
that should prevent such kind of memory leaks. The posted code was simplified.